# How to zoom out from Google maps in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am testing a map based app on the emulator. I have zoomed into the map by double clicking with the mouse on the screen, but can not zoom out.

Please tell me how to zoom out?

Comment: You could temporarily add the zoom controls: mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

Comment: does that mean, there is built in way of zooming out of maps in the emulator. I am facing same problem in the standard "google maps" app as well.

Comment: Enabling the controls would put the "zoom" icons on the screen in either the emulator or on a device that you could click to zoom in/out. It does look like if you double click and hold, then move your mouse up, it will zoom out. Look [here](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3139292?hl=en) under the section "zoom in and out with one hand"

Comment: @aProperFox Your comment is working for me, I was finding it since long. Thanks for the solution

Comment: Are these solutions specific to Google Maps? I have never gotten any to work.

Answer (score 120):

Double-click then hold the second click and move the mouse up(zoom out) or down(zoom in).

Comment: Among 10 answers to similar questions, this finally worked for me with a trackpad.

Answer (score 15):

if you use mac you should press cmd + press the mouse and move it diagonally

Answer (score 12):

Above answer didn't work.

For me on **Windows** these worked -

1. Trackpad - Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + double click and hold on a second
   click + drag in and out the cursor to zoom out and in respectively.
2. Trackpad/Mouse - Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click left button + drag in
   and out the cursor to zoom out and in respectively.
3. Touch screen - Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + drag in and out on the screen
   to zoom out and in respectively.

Answer (score 4):

On windows +  android studio emulator, press the ctrl key when emulator is in focus and mouse is inside the emulator / google maps app. You will see two green spots connected by a green line pop up. Move the mouse away from the center point while still holding the Ctrl key.

Left click (while still having the Ctrl key pressed) to confirm the zoom.

The longer the line, the more the map will zoom out.

Double click to zoom in.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Two ways you can do:

1. Press and hold Ctrl then press click button (mouse/trackpad) and move up/down to zoomin/zoomout
2. Double click and hold second click then move (mouse/trackpad) up/down to zoomin/zoomout.

Answer (score 2):

**We have two methods**

> If you use a mouse, you can Double-click then hold the second click
> and move the mouse up (zoom out) or down (zoom in).

> If you use the Trackpad, you can Double-click or Trible-Click then
> hold the second/third click and move the mouse up (zoom out) or down
> (zoom in). My laptop is used Trible-Click

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to zoom out of the emulator screen. After you have zoomed in appropriately and want to zoom out (return to original state), simply click the same zoom button again.

If instead, you want to zoom out in stages like the way you zoomed in, click the right mouse button.

Hope it helps you.