# How to zoom image in ios simulator?

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm using *react-native-image-pan-zoom* package and i want to test the functionality of zooming

I tried press cmd and mouse trackpad, it doesn't help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press 'option' key from the keyboard and mouse trackpad. The mouse pointer in simulator will be changed to two circles and after that by dragging on track pad you can zoom in and zoom out on the image. It works just like pinch gesture in native iOS application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to do that in Android?

Comment: @DevAS May be this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106174/how-to-zoom-out-from-google-maps-in-android-emulator